# Selenium WebDriver HTTP ERROR: 403 Forbidden for Proxy RequestURI=/session

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Running a Selenium 2 RemoteWebDriver server using `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar`.

I always get the error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 403
Forbidden for Proxy
RequestURI=/session
```

when connecting to it using the python WebDriver client:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444', {})
```

or any other various RemoteWebDriver client I could find.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution was simple: **Use the pathname `/wd/hub`**

i.e.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', {})
```

Comment: Mark this as the answer? There is a badge in it for you I think. http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner

Comment: Your answer is too simple. I did not understand. where should I write the code.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution to the exactly Problem, but for people getting this error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 403

Forbidden for Proxy
RequestURI=/

Powered by Jetty://
```

This error appears e.g. if multiple instances of Selenium are running, so you need to shut it down by browsing to URL:

```
http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
```

If another instance was running there should appear `okok`

Answer (score 1):

You have another process which is bound to same port i.e 4444.

Selenium Grid by default uses  port:4444.

You either need to kill the process which is bound to port:4444 or else you need to use another port(below used 5555) for your hub.

Use following in command prompt:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar -role hub -port 5555